# Doctrine One to One Empty Result

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Users Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="users", options={"collate":"utf8_general_ci", "charset":"utf8", "engine":"MyISAM"})
 */
class Users extends Entity {

    /**
     * One Users has One UserInformation. Inversed here.
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="UserInformation",mappedBy="users")
     */
    protected $userInformation;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $encrypted_password;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=10)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * @Column(type="smallint", options={"default":"0","comment":"0 : Doctor, 1 : Assistant, 2 : Student"}))
     * @var smallint
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=150)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $sef_link;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserInformation() {
        return $this->userInformation;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $userInformation
     */
    public function setUserInformation($userInformation) {
        $this->userInformation = $userInformation;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEncryptedPassword() {
        return $this->encrypted_password;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $encrypted_password
     */
    public function setEncryptedPassword($encrypted_password) {
        $this->encrypted_password = $encrypted_password;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt() {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $salt
     */
    public function setSalt($salt) {
        $this->salt = $salt;
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getType() {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $type
     */
    public function setType($type) {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSefLink() {
        return $this->sef_link;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $sef_link
     */
    public function setSefLink($sef_link) {
        $this->sef_link = $sef_link;
    }
}
```

UserInformation Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="user_information", options={"collate":"utf8_general_ci", "charset":"utf8", "engine":"MyISAM"})
 */
class UserInformation extends Entity {

    /**
     * One UserInformation has One Uses. Mapped here.
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Users")
     * @JoinColumn(name="uid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $surname;

    /**
     * @Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     * @var date
     */
    protected $born;

    /**
     * @Column(type="smallint", options={"default" : "0", "comment":"0 : Female, 1 : Male"}))
     * @var smallint
     */
    protected $gender;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text", length=65532, nullable=true)
     * @var text
     */
    protected $address;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $country_id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text", length=65532, nullable=true)
     * @var text
     */
    protected $about;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $institution;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text", length=65532, nullable=true)
     * @var text
     */
    protected $area_of_expertise;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $cv_path;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $facebook_link;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $twitter_link;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $instagram_link;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $linkedin_link;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $img_path;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $university;

    /**
     * @Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     * @var date
     */
    protected $university_graduated_at;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $md;

    /**
     * @Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     * @var date
     */
    protected $md_graduated_at;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $associate_professor;

    /**
     * @Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     * @var date
     */
    protected $associate_professor_graduated_at;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUsers() {
        return $this->users;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $users
     */
    public function setUsers($users) {
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSurname() {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $surname
     */
    public function setSurname($surname) {
        $this->surname = $surname;
    }

    /**
     * @return date
     */
    public function getBorn() {
        return $this->born;
    }

    /**
     * @param date $born
     */
    public function setBorn($born) {
        $this->born = $born;
    }

    /**
     * @return smallint
     */
    public function getGender() {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    /**
     * @param smallint $gender
     */
    public function setGender($gender) {
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }

    /**
     * @return text
     */
    public function getAddress() {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * @param text $address
     */
    public function setAddress($address) {
        $this->address = $address;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCountryId() {
        return $this->country_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $country_id
     */
    public function setCountryId($country_id) {
        $this->country_id = $country_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return text
     */
    public function getAbout() {
        return $this->about;
    }

    /**
     * @param text $about
     */
    public function setAbout($about) {
        $this->about = $about;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInstitution() {
        return $this->institution;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $institution
     */
    public function setInstitution($institution) {
        $this->institution = $institution;
    }

    /**
     * @return text
     */
    public function getAreaOfExpertise() {
        return $this->area_of_expertise;
    }

    /**
     * @param text $area_of_expertise
     */
    public function setAreaOfExpertise($area_of_expertise) {
        $this->area_of_expertise = $area_of_expertise;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCvPath() {
        return $this->cv_path;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $cv_path
     */
    public function setCvPath($cv_path) {
        $this->cv_path = $cv_path;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFacebookLink() {
        return $this->facebook_link;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $facebook_link
     */
    public function setFacebookLink($facebook_link) {
        $this->facebook_link = $facebook_link;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTwitterLink() {
        return $this->twitter_link;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $twitter_link
     */
    public function setTwitterLink($twitter_link) {
        $this->twitter_link = $twitter_link;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInstagramLink() {
        return $this->instagram_link;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $instagram_link
     */
    public function setInstagramLink($instagram_link) {
        $this->instagram_link = $instagram_link;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLinkedinLink() {
        return $this->linkedin_link;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $linkedin_link
     */
    public function setLinkedinLink($linkedin_link) {
        $this->linkedin_link = $linkedin_link;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImgPath() {
        return $this->img_path;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $img_path
     */
    public function setImgPath($img_path) {
        $this->img_path = $img_path;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUniversity() {
        return $this->university;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $university
     */
    public function setUniversity($university) {
        $this->university = $university;
    }

    /**
     * @return date
     */
    public function getUniversityGraduatedAt() {
        return $this->university_graduated_at;
    }

    /**
     * @param date $university_graduated_at
     */
    public function setUniversityGraduatedAt($university_graduated_at) {
        $this->university_graduated_at = $university_graduated_at;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMd() {
        return $this->md;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $md
     */
    public function setMd($md) {
        $this->md = $md;
    }

    /**
     * @return date
     */
    public function getMdGraduatedAt() {
        return $this->md_graduated_at;
    }

    /**
     * @param date $md_graduated_at
     */
    public function setMdGraduatedAt($md_graduated_at) {
        $this->md_graduated_at = $md_graduated_at;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAssociateProfessor() {
        return $this->associate_professor;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $associate_professor
     */
    public function setAssociateProfessor($associate_professor) {
        $this->associate_professor = $associate_professor;
    }

    /**
     * @return date
     */
    public function getAssociateProfessorGraduatedAt() {
        return $this->associate_professor_graduated_at;
    }

    /**
     * @param date $associate_professor_graduated_at
     */
    public function setAssociateProfessorGraduatedAt($associate_professor_graduated_at) {
        $this->associate_professor_graduated_at = $associate_professor_graduated_at;
    }
}
```

Service :

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password, $ip, $user_agent) {
        $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('App\Entity\Users');
        $user = $repository
            ->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->addSelect('ui') // to limit queries when doing $user->getUserInformation()
            ->innerJoin('u.userInformation', 'ui')
            ->where('u.email = :email')->setParameter('email', $email)->getQuery()->getSingleResult();

        if ($user == null)
            return 0; // user not found

        $salt = $user->getSalt();
        $encrypted_password = $user->getEncryptedPassword();
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);

        if ($hash == $encrypted_password) {
            return array(
                'id' => $user->getId(),
                'email' => $user->getEmail(),
                'type' => $user->getType(),
                'information' => $user->getUserInformation(),
                'created_at' => $user->getCreatedAt(),
                'updated_at' => $user->getUpdatedAt(),
                'is_deleted' => $user->getIsDeleted()
            );
        }
        return 1; // wrong email or password
    }
```

getUserInformation returns empty...
if i call `getResultArray()` instead of `getSingleResult()`, information returns with data. But this time, i can not use like this, `$user->getId()`. I just return the `$user`. 
So, i want to call `$user` as an object array. Information returns empty ?

> {   "error": false,   "user": {
>       "id": 27,
>       "email": "test@email.com",
>       "type": 1,
>       "information": {},
>       "created_at": {
>         "date": "2017-01-01 21:05:45.000000",
>         "timezone_type": 3,
>         "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
>       },
>       "updated_at": {
>         "date": "2017-01-01 21:05:45.000000",
>         "timezone_type": 3,
>         "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
>       },
>       "is_deleted": false   } }

Here is if `getQuery()->getArrayResult();` and `return $user;`

> {   "error": false,   "user": [
>       {
>         "email": "test@email.com",
>         "encrypted_password": "vjvyW2E9/MT7pll01S6uBeFIvO9lNzI1N2VjYjEx",
>         "salt": "e7257ecb11",
>         "type": 1,
>         "sef_link": "test-test",
>         "id": 27,
>         "created_at": {
>           "date": "2017-01-01 21:05:45.000000",
>           "timezone_type": 3,
>           "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
>         },
>         "updated_at": {
>           "date": "2017-01-01 21:05:45.000000",
>           "timezone_type": 3,
>           "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
>         },
>         "is_deleted": false,
>         "userInformation": {
>           "title": "test1",
>           "name": "test",
>           "surname": "test",
>           "born": null,
>           "gender": 0,
>           "address": null,
>           "country_id": null,
>           "about": null,
>           "institution": null,
>           "area_of_expertise": null,
>           "cv_path": null,
>           "facebook_link": null,
>           "twitter_link": null,
>           "instagram_link": null,
>           "linkedin_link": null,
>           "img_path": "default-profile-female.png",
>           "university": null,
>           "university_graduated_at": null,
>           "md": null,
>           "md_graduated_at": null,
>           "associate_professor": null,
>           "associate_professor_graduated_at": null,
>           "id": 16,
>           "created_at": {
>             "date": "2017-01-01 21:05:45.000000",
>             "timezone_type": 3,
>             "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
>           },
>           "updated_at": {
>             "date": "2017-01-01 21:05:45.000000",
>             "timezone_type": 3,
>             "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
>           },
>           "is_deleted": false
>         }
>       }   ] }

Comment: I have had this problem myself, when using dumps to check what data to get and it said null, have you tried (for example)  getUserInformation->getTitle(). What did that return

Comment: it returns data but if userinformation has multiple data, how can i get ? @KevinTheGreat

Comment: you mean you have an array? Just make a for loop, so foreach(users as getUserInformation). That should do it

Comment: @KevinTheGreat u are right, thank you :)

Comment: I'll make an answer so you can close this Q

Comment: It's because doctrine/symfony will only retrieve what is required for the request. With a dump you ask for nothing so receive nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem myself, when using dumps to check what data to get and it said null, have you tried (for example) `getUserInformation->getTitle()`.

Just make a for loop, so `foreach(users as getUserInformation)`. That should do it